# How can I prove rigorously that $\log x = o(\sqrt{x})$?

Tags: upper-bound

For my MSc thesis, I need to prove rigorously that $\log x = o(\sqrt{x}).$ How can I do it?

Comment: Compute the limit of the ratio by L'Hospital. By the way, the $\log$ grows slower than any positive power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{\log x}{x^{1/2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{(1/x)}{(1/2) x^{-1/2}} =
 \lim_{x \to \infty}  \frac{2}{x^{1/2}} = 0.
$$

Therefore, for any $c>0$, there exists some $n_0$ such that, for all $n \ge n_0$, $\log x \le c \sqrt{x}$. This satisfies the definition of [Little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Answer (score 2):

You will probably admit

$$z=o(e^z)$$ (which is obvious by Taylor).

Then with $z=\alpha\log(x)$,

$$\alpha\log(x)=o(x^\alpha)$$

and you can drop the factor $\alpha$ in the LHS.